# Bulk IP address verification

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how I can check not one IP address, but several at once. With the usual creation of a list, I constantly get an error.

```
import winsound
import socket
import time
import datetime
import os
import sys
LOG_FNAME = "network.log"
FILE = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), LOG_FNAME)
def send_ping_request(host = ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1'], timeout=3):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((host, 2440))
    except OSError as error:
        return False
    else:
        s.close()
        return True
def write_permission_check():
        try:
            with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                pass
        except OSError as error:
            print("Ошибка создания файла журнала")
            sys.exit()
        finally:
            pass
def calculate_time(start, stop):
        time_difference = stop - start
        seconds = float(str(time_difference.total_seconds()))
        return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)).split(".")[0]
def mon_net_connection(ping_freq=2):
        monitor_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        motd = "Мониторинг сетевого подключения начат в: " + str(monitor_start_time).split(".")[0] + " Отправка запроса ping в " + str(ping_freq) + " секунды"
        print(motd)

        with open(FILE, "a") as file:
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(motd + "\n")
while True:
        if send_ping_request():
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            down_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            fail_msg = "Сетевое соединение недоступно в: " + str(down_time).split(".")[0]
            winsound.Beep(400,400)
            print(fail_msg)
            with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                file.write(fail_msg + "\n")
                i = 0               
            while not send_ping_request():
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
                if i >= 3600:
                    i = 0
                    now = datetime.datetime.now()
                    continous_message = "Постоянная недоступность сети: " + str(now).split(".")[0]
                    print(continous_message)
                    with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                        file.write(continous_message + "\n")
                        up_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                        uptime_message = "Сетевое подключение восстановлено: " + str(up_time).split(".")[0]
                        down_time = calculate_time(down_time, up_time)
                        _m = "Подключение к сети было недоступно для " + down_time
                        print(uptime_message)
                        print(_m)

                        with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                            file.write(uptime_message + "\n")
                            file.write(_m + "\n")

            mon_net_connection()
```

I found the code on the Internet, since I'm a beginner, and I would like to understand how it all works. Maybe I need some library so that everything works fine?

The error I am getting :

```
TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not list
```

Comment: You should also share the error you are getting to make it easier for others to offer help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I seem to have corrected it

Comment: The error will occur here: *s.connect((host, 2440))* because the first item in the tuple should be a hostname (or IP address as a string). You're passing a list

Comment: How can I change the list to a tuple? I'm just not good at tuples and lists.

Comment: If a library function expects a string, you can't simply pass it a list and expect it to know that you want it to process every item in the list. You have to write that. Something like `for h in host: s.connect((h, 2440))`.

Comment: Isn't it okay if I assigned the list of IP addresses to the "host"?